# Next.js - Localhost refused to connect

Tags: npm, next.js, localhost

[image: Localhost]

### My issue

I want to learn Next.js, however when I create an empty Next.js project, I can't connect to my localhost when I run `npm run dev`. I am doing the following:

1. `npx create-next-app@latest`
2. I give my project a name.
3. `cd project-name`
4. `npm run dev`

This is all I see in the command prompt and after the last info-message, the server closes. I don't think my Next.js server starts correctly because it skips to a new line after I run `npm run dev`.

```
PS C:\Users\Username\Documents\Programmering\next13-experiment> npm run dev
next13-experiment@0.1.0 dev
next dev -p 3000

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
warn  - You have enabled experimental feature (appDir) in next.config.js.
info  - Thank you for testing `appDir` please leave your feedback at https://nextjs.link/app-feedback
warn  - Experimental features are not covered by semver, and may cause unexpected or broken application behavior. Use at your own risk.

info  - Using wasm build of next-swc

PS C:\Users\Username\Documents\Programmering\next13-experiment> npx create-next-app@latest --experimental-app
```

### What I've tried

I tried to check if there was any process using the port 3000 through `netstat -ano | findstr :3000`, but there was not. I couldn't find any in the Firewall Inbound Rules either.

I tried to Disable Firewall or any antivirus.

I adding `127.0.0.1 localhost` to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts and restart my PC.

I tried to change the port in the package.json.

[image: package.json]

### System

Windows 10, Node v18.15.0, Next 13.3.0, Not using any VPN

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was to uninstall Node v18.15.0, install Node v18.16.0, and then restart my PC. After doing this, the issue was resolved.

Comment: That couldn't possibly be the cause. Seems more like port mismatch. You are loading a different port than you have the NextJS app running on.

Comment: I agree, the version of node itself was not the cause. But at least it is an easy solution to reinstall Node, and might be an easy fix for others encountering the same issue. I did try to figure out if there was any apps using the port 3000, but was unable to find any.